# How to train-test split timeseries data in Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, train-test-split

I want to do a train test split on sorted Pyspark data frame based on time. Say that first 300 rows will be in train set and next 200 rows in test split.

I can select first first 300 rows with -

```python
train = df.show(300)
```

but how can I select the last 200 rows from Pyspark dataframe?

Comment: Related posts: [How to slice a pyspark dataframe in two row-wise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48884960/how-to-slice-a-pyspark-dataframe-in-two-row-wise/48888185#48888185), [Split Time Series pySpark data frame into test & train without using random split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51772908/split-time-series-pyspark-data-frame-into-test-train-without-using-random-spli/51773836#51773836), and [Is there a way to slice dataframe based on index in pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52792762/is-there-a-way-to-slice-dataframe-based-on-index-in-pyspark/52819758#52819758)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you have a dataframe `df` of size 500 sorted by the `time` column.

A simple way to go at it would be to use limit for the training set, and to do the same on the reversed dataframe for the test set.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import desc
train = df.limit(300)
test = df.orderBy(desc("time")).limit(200).orderBy("time")
```

Comment: What if we don't know size of dataframe and don't want to use count as well as window functions as count and window functions without partitionswould degrade the performance.

Comment: Compared to what?